# How to automate refreshing unread count

Tags: lotus, lotus-domino

A users workspace contains several chiklets that can often refer to retired servers and throws the error "You are not authorized" if sent a link to a new replica of that application.  To fix this issue the user can right click on any open space of the workspace and choose the 'Refresh Unread Count' option which removes any chiklets referring to retired servers.  I was able to get a handle on the workspace, desktop8.ndk, but the call to 'GetAllUnreadDocuments" does nothing.  I also looked in the Lotus C API  8.5 Reference and found a few entries of which I wasn't sure would solve my problem and checked the 6/7/8/8.5 forums.

So, the question is: can a routine be created that will automate the "Refresh Unread Count" process so that a call can be made to it from a button or during post open of the inbox?

I think the company Panagenda has a process that will remove old servers from the workspace, but not sure how they are going about that.  I did see that the 'cache.ndk' has a field, $SourceDbPath, that stores the server/path of databases.  Maybe parsing that and making a call to the server to open the 'names.nsf' is the way to go.  However, the 'cache.ndk' doesn't contain all applications on the user's workspace.

Thanks,

Dwain

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the workspace does not use ordinary Notes document structures and there are no published APIs specifically for accessing it.  Panagenda has done extensive research to reverse-engineer the data structures and has written their own low-level code to manipulate them.